# Permission denied error when running simple c++ program

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, clion

I get this error almost everytime i try to run a simple code on CLion.
I'm not trying to save the project in c drive.

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file A__IQ_test.exe: Permission denied
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   CMakeFiles\A__IQ_test.dir\build.make:95: recipe for target 'A__IQ_test.exe' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [A__IQ_test.exe] Error 1
>   mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/A__IQ_test.dir/all] Error 2
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/A__IQ_test.dir/all' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/A__IQ_test.dir/rule] Error 2
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/A__IQ_test.dir/rule' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [A__IQ_test] Error 2
>   Makefile:117: recipe for target 'A__IQ_test' failed

Comment: Check task manager to see if you already have the program open. Alternatively run the IDE as administrator, or change the output location

Answer (score 0):

This usually means your program is already running. You can't replace it with a new one while it's running. Ensure you've closed your program before you try to rebuild it. If you think you've done so, there may be a bug where it is hanging — attach your debugger to find out.